# checking network connections using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to check my connections via cordova, the logic that I'm trying to do, is:

if network connected give "greetings" alert, else replace elements of the main view.

my difficult is to if connection ok, just give greetings message. someone could check my code to help me do to?

regards

```
    function net(){

var theNet = navigator.connection.type;

var status = {};
status[Connection.NONE] = 'Sem acesso';
status[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Sem conexão';
status[Connection.WIFI] = 'Conexão wireless';
status[Connection.CELL] = 'Rede de operadora';
status[Connection.UNDEFINED] = 'Sem definição';

        //alert(status[suaNet]);

var result = "<p style='text-align:center'><img style='height:20em;width:20em;' src='img/icon-dove-1024x934.png'></p>";

var blank = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav'><li style='texto-menu'><a href='#'>Nothing here</a></li></ul>";    



if(Connection.NONE || Connection.UNKNOWN === false)
    {
        BootstrapDialog.alert("hi");
    }


else if(Connection.NONE || Connection.UNKNOWN === true){
        document.getElementById('div-inteira').innerHTML = result;
        document.getElementById('menu-barra-hamburguer').innerHTML = blank;
    }

else{
    console.log("doest works");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you doing this after device.ready function ? 
Try consoling the network type before you check for the connection's. And make sure your using the correct implementation of the plugin.